# Is it possible to store the Documents in One-drive instead of SharePoint content database?

Tags: sharepoint-server, onedrive-for-business

Need to upload the documents in SharePoint, but it needs to store all those documents in one-drive and reference should be in the document library.
Is it possible in SharePoint 2013. I have installed SharePoint server 2013 service pack 1.

I am asking on SharePoint On-premise environment not in Office 365
Will you please tell me the solution for that.

Comment: Are you talking about configuring SharePoint 2013 on-prem to work with OneDrive for Business?

Comment: Yes. i need that only process only

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive is still SharePoint, so it will still store them in a content database. You could do it like this:

1. Store all the files in a OneDrive location.
2. Enable Management of Content Types in your document library.
3. Add Link to a document content type.
4. Create entries as link to a document that point to all of files in the OneDrive location.

In the end though, the files are still stored in a content database, whether it is your SharePoint site or your OneDrive.

Comment: Actually i don't want to store my document in SharePoint document library, only reference link is available in SharePoint, but document is stored in one-drive my account.

Comment: Then this is what you'd do, store the file in a OneDrive, then use the Link to a Document content type to make it look as if it is in a SharePoint Document library.

Comment: what you are saying is correct, but my requirement is i have an account in one-drive which has default storage space of 15 GB. and i have separate SharePoint server 2013. Once i upload the document in SharePoint document library it should be stored in one-drive not in SharePoint content database and moreover only reference link is available in SharePoint document library for that one-drive storage

Answer (score 0):

If it's something like the following diagram that you are looking for:

[image]

Then you need to configure redirect to Office 365 with OneDrive for Business.

You need to have User Profile Service set up and working and do a couple of configuration steps. Follow [THIS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn627525.aspx) article and you'll set up everything easily.

[HERE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn197168.aspx) you can find more SharePoint 2013 Hybrid configuration roadmaps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: what you are saying is correct, but my requirement is i have an account in one-drive which has default storage space of 15 GB. and i have separate SharePoint server 2013. Once i upload the document in SharePoint document library it should be stored in one-drive not in SharePoint content database and moreover only reference link is available in SharePoint document library for that one-drive storage.